# How to change the write concern with JavaScript insert into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to test the insert rate with write concern = 0. But don't know where to change the JavaScript code.

```
db.testData.insert( 
        {"global_node_id": 1,
        "some_node_id": 1,
        "data": "data"})
```

Here is one line in js to insert. I didn't understand where to put the `{w:0}`.

Do I specify the write concern when I connect to the database?  Or in the insert command?

I tried the following:

```
conn = new Mongo()
db = conn.getDB("myDatabase",{w:0});
```

No error pops up, but it does not speed up.  Is this the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming by "js code" you mean "in the mongo shell", as that is what your code implies, you specify unacknowledged write concern in insert operations like so:

```
> db.test.insert({a: 1}, {writeConcern: {w: 0}})
WriteResult({ })
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**

`db.testData.insert( 
  {
    'global_node_id': 1,
    'some_node_id': 1,
    'data': 'data'
  },
  {
    writeConcern: {w:0}
  }
)`

**Long version**

I'm assuming (giving your code and the node.js tag) that you are actually using the NodeJS driver for MongoDB, not the mongo shell.

The syntax for `insert` is:

`collection.insert(docs[[, options], callback])`

(as can be seen in [the docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html)).

So, you have an optional second argument that stands for the options. You can pass the write concern in the options as shown there.